# How do I reset my TFA token in Coinbase?

Tags: security, coinbase.com, authentication, two-factor

I would like to move my Coinbase Two-factor authentication token from one device to another. I cannot find a location on their website to disable TFA once it has been set up, or to move the token to another device. What am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should have the option to remove / change the 2-factor Authentication under Settings >> Personal Details, though this may have changed. My guess is you'll probably need to contact Coinbase support if nothing else has worked so far: http://support.coinbase.com/customer/portal/emails/new